# Status Change in Elsevier

Tags: publications

What does it mean - status changed from "with editor" to "decision in process" directly in Elsevier within 10 days of submission?

Comment: Perhaps an admin can merge the answers below with the original question?

Answer (score 3):

Everything is explained here in detail:

https://service.elsevier.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/5971/kw/track/c/10528/supporthub/publishing/

> **Decision in Process** The Editor has registered a decision in the system. The decision may need to be confirmed by the Editor-in-Chief first. The Editor will email you directly with the overall editorial decision, Editor and/or reviewer comments, and further instructions.

Answer (score 2):

> When a journal displays the “decision in process” status, it means
>   that the editorial board is in the process of making the final
>   decision about your paper. At this stage when the journal decision is
>   in process, the editor will go through the revised manuscript and your
>   replies to the reviewer comments before coming to a decision. The
>   editor might decide to consult the peer reviewers once more.
>   Sometimes, there may be quite a few papers lined up before yours. This
>   is why this stage might take long. There’s no specific time frame for
>   this; the time may vary depending on the journal and the field. I
>   think it would be reasonable to write to the editor to inquire about
>   the status of your paper if you haven’t received a response even a
>   month after the last status change.

Source: https://www.editage.com/insights/what-is-the-meaning-of-decision-in-process-status

Since you've received "[the] status changed from 'with editor' to 'decision in process'...within 10 days of submission," it might-well be that the editor has decided on a desk reject (perhaps for being out-of-scope), a request for minor amendments (e.g., if you didn't follow procedure), acceptance (albeit, perhaps unlikely), or ...

Comment: In principle it could be that the editor is reviewing it. If the journal is highly specific it could happen.

Comment: @Alchimista That's true. Albeit, I think unlikely. I included it anyway (and upvoted your comment).